# SVG images not getting full width of viewport in ie

Tags: html, css, image, internet-explorer, svg

I am using SVG image with inline images, and working fine other browsers except internet explore. in ie its showing smallest size  but actual image is 100% width of screen , below is my SVG code

```
<code>
 <section class="position-relative d-flex">
    <svg
        class="d-none d-lg-block"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
width="100%" height=""
        viewBox="0 0 1920 1519">

<image width="1920" height="1519" xlink:href="./images/-image.png"/>
                
               
                
              <a href="#">
<image width="317" height="75" transform="translate(974 1325)" xlink:href="./images/-image2.png"/>
</a>
              <a href="#"> 
<image width="317" height="75" transform="translate(591 655)" xlink:href="./images/-image3.png"/>
</a>
              <a href="#">
<image width="317" height="75" transform="translate(594 1325)" xlink:href="./images/-image4.png"/>
</a>
</svg>
</section>
</code>



I tried this css from and answer in this site, this also not working for me.

only when I give some fix height and width only its  showing bigger size I want to use 100% width and make svg adjusting like its showing in other browsers
```

tried to use jquery way to get width of viewport and add it to svg then also not working.

```
 <code>
     @media all and (-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active) {
          img{
            flex: 0 0 auto;  /* IE */
        object-fit: scale-down; /* FF */
        flex: 1;
        width: 100vw; 
            max-height: 100%;
          }
        }
        @media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
          svg {
            width: 100vw; 
          }
        }

</code>


if anyone could suggest a way to make this SVG showing full screen in ie it would be very helpful.
```

Comment: IE simply doesn't support [vw units](https://caniuse.com/?search=vw).

Comment: @RobertLongson could you suggest any solution for this

Comment: Sure, rewrite your solution not to use units that IE does not support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that you had already added the `viewbox` in the `svg`.

Other then that, I suggest you add `width="1920" height="1519"` instead of `width="100%" height=""`.

IE browser will give similar output as other browsers.

Modified code:

```
<section class="position-relative d-flex">
   <svg
      class="d-none d-lg-block"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
      xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
      width="1920" height="1519"
      viewBox="0 0 1920 1519">
      <image width="1920" height="1519" xlink:href="./images/-image.png"/>
      <a href="#">
         <image width="317" height="75" transform="translate(974 1325)" xlink:href="./images/-image2.png"/>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
         <image width="317" height="75" transform="translate(591 655)" xlink:href="./images/-image3.png"/>
      </a>
      <a href="#">
         <image width="317" height="75" transform="translate(594 1325)" xlink:href="./images/-image4.png"/>
      </a>
   </svg>
</section>
```

Output in IE 11 browser:

[image]